# loop in different time intervals, python

Tags: python

How to loop a function with two different intervals?

I want the 1st instance running every 3 seconds and the 2nd instance running every 6 seconds

```
import time
def test(name, frequency):
    while True:
        print(name)
        time.sleep(frequency)
```

But it only runs the first function, I want them running in the same time but two different intervals (3seconds and 6 seconds)

```
test("one", frequency=3)
test("two", frequency=6)
```

Thank you!

Comment: Take a look at `threading` or `multiprocessing` modules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As **Pedro Maia** commented, python naturally can't make simultaneous *stuff*. So you need a multiprocessing module. For instance you can make a dictionary with the name and frequencies to use and access *that* dictionary by processes to join. Using the multiprocessing library (comes in the standard library) you can use the multiprocessing.Process(target=*function name*,args=[*arg1*,*arg2*...]) function. Each multiprocess will be assigned a different part of your pc (roughly speaking) to achieve or run the task. When you call the processes with start() you can run parallel tasks, and then you must call join() on them, thats where the script will run on a single *process* again. You may need to add an innate "stopper" to your function (that stops the while loop) since the multiprocessing may become *blind* to counters *outside* the function.

```
For instance:
import time
def test(name, frequency):
    k=0
    while k<500:
        print(name)
        k+=1
        time.sleep(frequency)

a=multiprocessing.Process(target=test,args=["one",3])

b=multiprocessing.Process(target=test,args=["two",6])

a.start()

b.start()

a.join()

b.join()
```

This is an oversimplification and it may be useful to look for a youtube multiprocessing tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

If you only need to do it for 3 and 6 second intervals, you could get away with not using threading or multiprocessing by skipping the 6 second interval function for every odd iteration.

```
import time

counter = 0
while True:
    if counter%2 == 0:
        # 6 second interval function
        print("6 second function")
        
    # 3 second interval function
    print("3 second function")

    counter += 1
    time.sleep(3)
```

Note that your 3 second interval might not actually be 3 seconds, it will be 3 seconds plus however long it takes to execute your function

Comment: This makes a lot more sense that fussing around with multiprocessing if the functions are short lived.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to know how to [multithread](https://realpython.com/intro-to-python-threading/). Having multiple threads allows you to do multiple things at once.

The link shows you how to multithread in python.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the tips
here is what I find that works

```
t1 = threading.Thread(target=test, args=("one", 3))
t2 = threading.Thread(target=test, args=("two", 6))
t1.start()
t2.start()
t1.join()
t2.join()
```